# How to make sum of following numbers?

Tags: button

How to make simple sum of following numbers?

```
ButtonBar[{"1" :> Print[1], "2" :> Print[2], "3" :> Print[3], "4" :> Print[4]}]
```

If I press buttons, for example  $\lbrace 1,1,2,3,4 \rbrace$ there is a list of numbers

[image]

I want to evaluate only sum of this numbers $1+1+2+3+4=11$,  instead vertical list of numbers

Comment: How about `x = 0; Dynamic[x]` and then `ButtonBar[{"1" :> (x += 1), "2" :> (x += 2), "3" :> (x += 3), "4" :> (x += 4)}]`?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer - You might want to include a `Reset`: `ButtonBar[{"Reset" :> (x = 0), "1" :> (x += 1), "2" :> (x += 2), 
  "3" :> (x += 3), "4" :> (x += 4)}]`

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer -  For a variables number of buttons: `btnBar[n_Integer?Positive]:= 
 ButtonBar[{"Reset" :> (x = 0), 
    ToString[#] :> (x += #) & /@ Range[n]} // Flatten]`